# how can I avoid nested loop here ? using php

Tags: php, loops, nested

I have this loop here and what I want to do is save all of those items from each year and quarter in to my array so i can get the averages per quarter but doing it like this seems way to bad to me. and I cant figure of a wait of doing this

what am doing here is reading from my jason array  the quarter and year and saving it to each element of my 12 element array. but I am pretty sure its bad.

```
foreach($Jarray as $obj) {
    if ($obj->quarter == "1" and $obj->year == "2015" ) {
        $tarray[0] = $tarray[0] + $obj->sales;

    }
    if ($obj->quarter == "2" and $obj->year == "2015" ) {
        $tarray[1] = $tarray[1] + $obj->sales;
    }
    if ($obj->quarter == "3" and $obj->year == "2015" ) {
        $tarray[2] = $tarray[2] + $obj->sales;

    }
    if ($obj->quarter == "4" and $obj->year == "2015" ) {
        $tarray[3] = $tarray[3] + $obj->sales;

    }
    if ($obj->quarter == "1" and $obj->year == "2016" ) {
        $tarray[4] = $tarray[4] + $obj->sales;

    }
    if ($obj->quarter == "2" and $obj->year == "2016" ) {
        $tarray[5] = $tarray[5] + $obj->sales;

    }
    if ($obj->quarter == "3" and $obj->year == "2016" ) {
        $tarray[6] = $tarray[6] + $obj->sales;

    }
    if ($obj->quarter == "4" and $obj->year == "2016" ) {
        $tarray[7] = $tarray[7] + $obj->sales;

    }
    if ($obj->quarter == "1" and $obj->year == "2017" ) {
        $tarray[8] = $tarray[8] + $obj->sales;

    }
    if ($obj->quarter == "2" and $obj->year == "2017" ) {
        $tarray[9] = $tarray[9] + $obj->sales;

    }
    if ($obj->quarter == "3" and $obj->year == "2017" ) {
        $tarray[10] = $tarray[10] + $obj->sales;

    }
    if ($obj->quarter == "4" and $obj->year == "2017" ) {
        $tarray[11] = $tarray[11] + $obj->sales;

    }
    $count ++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to calculate the offset of the element by using the year and quarter to work it out...

```
$offset  = (($obj->year-2015)*4)+$obj->quarter-1;
```

So with 2015 Q 1 - this gives 0, 2017 Q4 gives 11.  So the code comes down to...

```
$tarray = array_fill(0,12,0);
foreach ( $Jarray as $obj ) {
    $offset  = (($obj->year-2015)*4)+$obj->quarter-1;
    $tarray[$offset] += $obj->sales;
}
```